# How to search data in gridview using a TextBox value with an Oracle Database

Tags: c#, oracle, winforms, datagridview

I am trying to show Oracle Data in a DataGridView in my Windows Form Application but it just returns a grey blank view. My code for this currently is:

```
        string insertquery = "select * from Candidate where CandidateName like '"+ txtBoxSearchData.Text +"%'";

        OracleConnection con = new OracleConnection(oradb);
        con.Open();
        OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand();
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.CommandText = insertquery;

        try
        {
            OracleDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

            OracleDataAdapter orada = new OracleDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
            orada.Fill(dataTable);
            dataTable.Load(reader);
            BindingSource bSource = new BindingSource();
            bSource.DataSource = dataTable;
            dataGridViewSearch.DataSource = bSource;
            orada.Update(dataTable);

        }
        catch(ArgumentException ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
        catch(OracleException ex1)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex1.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            cmd.Dispose();
            con.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

I am positive I do not require all those functions in my Try statement but I have come across many different methods to do this - I just included all of those into my code to experiment. The connection string is correct too as I have succeeded in adding data into the tables through queries in another part of my application.

Answer (score 0):

Doing something like the following should be enough. There should be no need for an OracleDataAdapter or BindingSource. Just can't test it here, as I do not have an Oracle database around.

```
public void fillDataGrid()
    {
        try
        {
            using(OracleConnection connection = new OracleConnection("connectstring"))
            using(OracleCommand cmd = new OracleCommand("select * from my super table", connection ))
            {
                connection .Open();
                using(OracleDataReader oracleDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                     DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
                     dataTable.Load(oracleDataReader );
                     myDataGrid.DataSource = dataTable;
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
 }
```